# Can't find substring in an output from paramiko's channel

Tags: python, paramiko

Python 3.7.4. I'm starting a bash script using Paramiko:

```
        channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
        channel.get_pty()
        channel.invoke_shell()
        time.sleep(1)
        if channel.recv_ready():
            output = channel.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        print(output)

        cd = 'cd test/'
        install = './test.sh'
        channel.send(cd + '\n')
        channel.send(install + '\n')

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if channel.recv_ready():
                output = channel.recv(2048).decode('ascii')
                if (r'User \x1b[1mtest\x1b[m\x0f does not exist, creating test user..' in output):
                    print('Test script started successfully')
                    break
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                if not(channel.recv_ready()):
                    break
```

Part of the output value in the while loop is:

```
'cd test/\r\n[root@hostname test]# ./test.sh\r\nUser \x1b[1mtest\x1b[m\x0f does not exist, creating test user..\r\nuseradd: warning: the home directory already exists.\r\n(...)'
```

I can't figure out why `(r'User \x1b[1mtest\x1b[m\x0f does not exist, creating test user..' in output)` is not true. I tried decoding the output to UTF-8, using normal string with backslash escape sequence but that didn't work either.

I had the same issue in other parts of the code with different strings so to get it working I shortened them to remove all slashes. But it would be good to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you try to decode it to utf8 and use a normal string, not a raw one? (without the r)

Comment: It works. I must have checked normal string with ascii decoding only. Thanks mate.
Do you know why raw string does not work?

Comment: Or maybe I checked normal string with backslash escape sequences which I thought were necessary.

Comment: It doesn't work with raw string because for example r'\n' will mean a character \ followed by a character r, not the escape sequence \n which means a newline. You can try for example print(r'\n') and print('\n')

Comment: Thanks. I was first doing prints and printed raw string looked exactly the same as the output value. But when I print that value \n and \r are replaced with newlines. That was a bit tricky for me.

Comment: Plus, you have shell escape character, to indicate bold, colors etc, so indeed it is sometimes misleading why the printing is not what you excpect. I added an answer for clarification, for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape sequences such as `\r` `\n` or `\x1b[1m` won't have the same meaning if you use a raw string. For example `r"\n"` means literally a character \ then a character n, but `"\n"` means a new line:

```
>>> print(r"\n")
\n
>>> print("\n")


>>>
```

So you should first decode to utf-8, then use a normal string, not a raw one.